# Animate a character by using a recorded video

Tags: animation, video, motion-capture

I want to animate a character in a realistic but easy way. I was thinking that I could use videos of me performing the actions I want to have on my characters, however I can't find a way of placing the videos and make the character to follow my movements in an automated way, like motion tracking. How can I animate automatically using this technique? Are there any Plug-ins to work like this? Is this mehod actually more useful than standard animation techniques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a Microsoft Kinnect and the NiMate software. The app captures your movement in the camera and converts it to mocap data you can import into Blender and apply to a rigged armature for your character.

https://ni-mate.com

[image]